# Safe way to call a widget with namespace, with empty selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, widget

The jQueryUi `$.widget` factory creates classes that can be used on two ways:

1. `$("mySelector").myWidget(myOptions)`; and
2. `$.myNamespace.myWidget(myOptions, mySelector)`.

The first way does not support namespace for widgets, so I prefer using the second version. My problem is that the version that support namespace throws an exception when `mySelector` doesn't match any html element (ie `$(mySelector).length == 0`). Is there any *beautiful* way to avoid this problem? I am developing an internal framework and would not like to have unnecessary `if` conditions.

For reference, I've already read (and I think I understood):

- http://api.jqueryui.com/1.10/jQuery.widget/
- http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/extending-widgets/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both calls are not exactly the same. The first one will iterate through each elements of your **selector** and apply the **widget**, but not the second. 
See:

```js
$.ui.draggable('', 'div')
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid black;
}
.ui-draggable {
  border: solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
```

To make it equivalent you'd need to use **$.each**, which would apply it to all of the elements in your selector and get rid of your error as well.

Like this for example:

```js
$('div').each(function(){
 $.ui.draggable('', this)
});

$('.empty').each(function(){
 $.ui.draggable('', this)
});
```

```css
div
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not exactly, @Julien. In my tests, the code `$.ui.draggable(null, "div")` behaves the same as `$("div").draggable(null)` -- it is not necessary to call `$("div").each(...)`. It does solves the problem, but with two drawbacks: it introduces overhead and, more important, leave to the _client code_ the responsibility to remember this. I am working on implementing `_createWidget` on the base class and removing error conditions for the selectors there. What do you think about it?

Comment: See edit, from what I try it's not equivalent. Maybe I'm missing something, but from my understanding the the draggable function is basically using each on the jquery object and applying _createwidget. That's why there's no validation on createWidget, because it's taken care of by a 'each' somewhere.

Comment: Hi, @JulienGregoire, actually, I got help from jquery forum and the syntax `$.namespace.widget(options, selector)` should only accept a *single* DOMElement, a HTML string or undefined. It worked on my code because of a coincidence (they use query constructor to normalize the parameter). Of course this is not supported, so I changed my code to use a `$(...).each` pattern, as you suggested. Thank you!

[https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-2-2-0-trows-error-3649-acceptdata-when-widget-is-called-with-namespace-over-a-selector-that-has-no-match]